# how to insert fast csv data to mysql?

Tags: mysql, insert, datagrip

I'm trying to insert CSV data which is 1.2GB to mysql with DataGrip,

and It takes about 20 minutes. So slow.

This is not local CSV file to local mysql but local CSV file to cloud instance mysql.

I want to do this within 5 minutes. How can I do this more fast? :D

Comment: You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: 20 minutes from local csv to cloud mysql seems pretty darned reasonable to me. Where are your bottlenecks? Is it the network or the ingestion into mysql?

Comment: How long does it take to transfer 1.2GB between your machine and the cloud?  How away (in milliseconds) is the cloud?